# Why is my .sh file not running in LXDE/autostart on Debian but works on Raspbian?

Tags: boot, debian, firmware, sh

I'm switching from a raspberry pi (raspbian) to a tinkerboard (debian) and am unable to get the scripts running in my autostart file that I use in raspbian working on debian.

On Raspbian:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Then I enter

sh /home/pi/Firmware/ws_sl.sh
On Debian, I've made some adjustments (LXDE instead of LXDE-pi) but unfortunately the script isn't starting on boot.

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
sh /home/linaro/Firmware/ws_sl.sh
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Raspbian.  I solved it by calling my bash file in an lxterminal window using an `@lxterminal` command in the autostart file.

You also need to be sure you are editing the correct autostart, as there is one in the `/etc` tree for all users, and there can be an override in the `/home/{user}` tree.

My full solution is here https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/112365/119486